# Override/Intercept all jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, interceptor

I was trying to override all jQuery functions to perform an action whenever jQuery was called (for auditing purposes or other reasons). However I probably need to get the same parameters a function receives in order to make the following code work:

```js
function __wrapjQuery () {
  var wrapper = this;

  
  alert('Wrapping');
    
     
  var functions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($.fn).filter(function (p)   {
    return ( typeof( $.fn[p] ) === 'function');
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    wrapper.oldTempjQueryFunction = $.fn[functions[i]];
    $.fn[functions[i]] = function () {
      var self = this;
      self.wrappedFunction = wrapper.oldTempjQueryFunction; 
      var returnVar = self.wrappedFunction.call(this);
      alert('jQuery was called'); 
      return returnVar;
    }
  } 
   
}

$().ready(self.__wrapjQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#FF0000">
  ELEMENT
  </div>

<button onclick="$('#myDiv').remove()">Remove Element</button>
```

However the code below, where I specify the function to override (`remove`) ,works (maybe because of the parameters):

```js
function __wrapjQuery () {
 var wrapper = this;
 
 alert('Wrapping'); 
 wrapper.wrappedRemoveFunction = $.fn.remove;
    $.fn.remove = function () {
      var self = this;
      var returnVar = wrapper.wrappedRemoveFunction.call(this);
      alert('jQuery was called to remove'); 
      return returnVar;
    }
   
}

$().ready(self.__wrapjQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#FF0000">
  ELEMENT
  </div>

<button onclick="$('#myDiv').remove()">Remove Element</button>
```

How would I replace all functions (even those with parameters, like `each`) and keep jQuery working normally? Let's say I want to audit the most used methods from jQuery.

Comment: First obvious question would be why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl Let's say I want to audit the most used methods from jQuery.

Comment: so what happens when you remove `&& $.fn[p] == "remove"` and try to use `$.fn.each`? Or when you try chaining methods?

Comment: @charlietfl the fiddle had an error. If I put `p == "each"` I find out that it needs two parameters `jQuery.fn.jQuery.each(callback, args)` and then the `.call` will fail. However if I handle every single jQuery function manually it would work, but if I upgraded jQuery having more functions the script would be outdated.

Comment: You're overwriting `wrapper.oldTempjQueryFunction` each time through the loop. Also, inside the functions, `this` will be the object that the jQuery method was called on, not the jQuery object itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap all jQuery object methods to collect whatever statistics you want with code like this:

```
// place this right after jQuery and any jQuery plugins are installed
(function($) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames($.fn).filter(function (p)   {
        return ( typeof( $.fn[p] ) === 'function' && p !== "init");
    }).forEach(function(funcName) {
        var orig = $.fn[funcName];
        $.fn[funcName] = function() {
            console.log(funcName + " jQuery method called");
            return orig.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7Ls0qkvb/

If you also wanted to include static methods, you could do a similar enumeration of the methods on the `jQuery` object.

---

Note, because `$.fn.init()` is called as a constructor and thus needs different treatment in how it is handled (you can't use `.apply()` with a constructor), I bypassed recording that method.  I have not searched through jQuery to find any other methods called as a constructor, but they would likely need special treatment also.

---

Here's a more advanced version that can even log `.init()` and any other method called as a constructor: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uf531xzb/.  It detects if a method is called with `new` and acts accordingly.

Comment: Where does `arguments` come from?

Comment: @ClayKaboom - It's built into every function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

> How would I replace all functions (even those with parameters, like
>   each) and keep jQuery working normally?

You can retrieve [`jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js`](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js) plugin, include lines `354-373` for ability to use utilize [deprecated](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-sub-removed) [`jQuery.sub()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/).

> `jQuery.sub()` Returns [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>
> Description: Creates a new copy of jQuery whose properties and methods
>   can be modified without affecting the original jQuery object.

```js
// https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js, lines 354-373
jQuery.sub = function() {
  function jQuerySub(selector, context) {
    return new jQuerySub.fn.init(selector, context);
  }
  jQuery.extend(true, jQuerySub, this);
  jQuerySub.superclass = this;
  jQuerySub.fn = jQuerySub.prototype = this();
  jQuerySub.fn.constructor = jQuerySub;
  jQuerySub.sub = this.sub;
  jQuerySub.fn.init = function init(selector, context) {
    var instance = jQuery.fn.init.call(this, selector, context, rootjQuerySub);
    return instance instanceof jQuerySub ?
      instance :
      jQuerySub(instance);
  };
  jQuerySub.fn.init.prototype = jQuerySub.fn;
  var rootjQuerySub = jQuerySub(document);
  // migrateWarn( "jQuery.sub() is deprecated" );
  return jQuerySub;
};


// do stuff with copy of jQuery
var __wrapjQuery = jQuery.sub();
__wrapjQuery.pluginName = "wrapper";
__wrapjQuery.fn.remove = function() {
  console.log(__wrapjQuery.fn.remove, $.fn.remove);
  alert(__wrapjQuery.pluginName);
}

__wrapjQuery(".wrapper").click(function() {
  __wrapjQuery(this).remove()
});


$(".jquery").click(function() {
  console.log($.fn.remove, __wrapjQuery.fn.remove);
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="wrapper">wrapper <code>.remove()</code>
</button>
<button class="jquery">jQuery <code>.remove()</code>
</button>
```

Comment: Very helpful! It will be useful for future reference! Thanks!